# openDatabaseSync in Javascript in QT-Quick

Tags: javascript, qt, function, qml

In the main.qml I have the import of a javascript file:

```
import "./js/noteDB.js" as NoteDB
```

And inside it I want to play a bit with the database to save and load states, so I call,

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    NoteDB.openDB()
}
```

where openDB() is defined in the noteDB.js file:

```
function openDB() {
      print("noteDB.createDB()")
     _db = openDatabaseSync("StickyNotesDB", "1.0",
                            "The stickynotes Databes", 1000000);
     createNoteTable();
}
```

But I get the following error:
ReferenceError: openDatabaseSync is not defined*

PS: Following a bug report in Qt-Quick I tried also, instead of calling openDB(), to do this:
var _db = NoteDB.LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("StickyNotesDB", "1.0",
                                                   "TheStickynotesDatabes", 1000000);
but give a similar error:
*TypeError: Cannot call method 'openDatabaseSync' of undefined*

Thank you to anyone that can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested with my Qt 5.2 and it seems to work when I have

```
 1  import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
 2  import QtQuick 2.0
 3  import "noteDB.js" as NoteDB
 4
 5  Item {
 6          Component.onCompleted: {
 7                      NoteDB.openDB();
 8          }
 9  }
```

and

```
 1  function openDB() {
 2            print("noteDB.createDB()")
 3            var _db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("StickyNotesDB", "1.0",
 4                                             "The stickynotes Databes", 1000000);
 5  }
```

So, I recommend you to write `LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync` and double check that `import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0` is present.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this exact method gives me 
*"Reference Error: LocalStorage is not defined"*

Comment: I tried also to 
.import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0 
in the .js file, but nothing... :)

Comment: I'll see this error if I remove `import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0` from qml file. Maybe your Qt version differs somehow from Qt5.2? For example, you maybe should use another version number in qml file... Anyway, You can try to join #qt-quick on Freenode IRC to advertize your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
.import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0 as Sql
...
var _db = Sql.LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("StickyNotesDB", "1.0",
                                          "The stickynotes Databes", 1000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0 as Sql

Rectangle {
    color: "white"
    width: 200
    height: 100

Text {
    text: "?"
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    function findGreetings() {
        var db = Sql.LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("QDeclarativeExampleDB", "1.0", "The Example QML SQL!", 1000000);

        db.transaction(
            function(tx) {
                // Create the database if it doesn't already exist
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Greeting(salutation TEXT, salutee TEXT)');

                // Add (another) greeting row
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Greeting VALUES(?, ?)', [ 'hello', 'world' ]);

                // Show all added greetings
                var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Greeting');

                var r = ""
                for (var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
                    r += rs.rows.item(i).salutation + ", " + rs.rows.item(i).salutee + "\n"
                }
                text = r
            }
        )
    }
    Component.onCompleted: findGreetings()
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code-only answers but also add a little textual explanation about how and why it works and what makes it different from the other answers.